# Why does a normal class instantiation cause an unhandled overflow exception?

Tags: c#, class, exception, stack-overflow

I can't see anything other than an normal class initialized.

Here is the class, class Bet.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab_ADayAtTheRaces
{
public class Bet : Form1
{
    public int Bets_Joe;
    public int Bets_Bob;
    public int Bets_Al;
    public int Dog_Joe;
    public int Dog_Bob;
    public int Dog_Al;

    public int Amount;
    public int Dog;
    public Guy Bettor;

    public string GetDescription()
    {
        Amount = (int)numericUpDownBucksToBet.Value;
        Dog = (int)numericUpDownDogToBetOn.Value;
        //Bettor =
        return Bettor + " placed a bet in the amount of " + Amount + " bucks on dog number " + Dog;
    }

    public int PayOut(int Winner)
    {
        return Winner;
    }

    public void MakeBets()
    {
        if (joeRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            Bets_Joe = (int)numericUpDownBucksToBet.Value;
            Dog_Joe = (int)numericUpDownDogToBetOn.Value;
        }

        else if (bobRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            Bets_Bob = (int)numericUpDownBucksToBet.Value;
            Dog_Bob = (int)numericUpDownDogToBetOn.Value;
        }

        else if (alRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            Bets_Al = (int)numericUpDownBucksToBet.Value;
            Dog_Al = (int)numericUpDownDogToBetOn.Value;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
namespace Lab_ADayAtTheRaces
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bet bets = new Bet(); //**THIS LINE THROWS THE STACKOVERFLOW EXCEPTION**

    Greyhound[] dogs = new Greyhound[3];
```

It wants me to say something more but I have nothing more to add so I'll just add some lines here and here.
It wants me to say something more but I have nothing more to add so I'll just add some lines here and here.
It wants me to say something more but I have nothing more to add so I'll just add some lines here and here.
It wants me to say something more but I have nothing more to add so I'll just add some lines here and here.
Any help is muchly appriciated... thanks in advance
Kristjan

Comment: Please add the exact exception type and message.

Comment: Just as a side note: you should use public properties instead of exposing your fields (Bets_Joe, Bets_Bob, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your `Bet` inherits from `Form1`, so `Bet()` will call to `Form1()`, and `Form1()` will again call to `Bet()` inside it -> again and again -> `StackOverflow`

**Tip**: We should never call the constructor of a class in its constructor or its class definition like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1(){
    }
    public Form1(string s){
    }
    public Form1 f = new Form1();//this will throw StackOverflowException
    public Form1 f = new Form1("");//this will also throw StackOverflowException       
    //Form2 inherits from Form1
    public Form2 f = new Form2(); //this will throw StackOverflowException
}
//or
public class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1(){
        Form1 f = new Form1();//This will throw stackoverflowexception
        Form1 f = new Form1("");//This won't throw any exception
    }
    public Form1(string s){
    }
}
```

When a class is initialized, all the members are initialized first before calling the constructor, hence the line `Bet bets = new Bet();` is executed before initializing your `Form1`. So you have to avoid it. To initialize `new Bet()`, you should call it in some event so that the event will never be fired by calling the constructor, such as `Load`.

```
Bet bets;//Just declare it without initializing it
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   bets = new Bet();
}
```